# scrapy fail to cooperate with python3.7

Tags: python, scrapy, syntax-error, twisted, python-3.7

I failed to install twisted by pip command, so I manually downloaded the .whl file and got it installed( version 18.7.0).  Only after i did that, my laptop could install scrapy;  however, it seems that the twisted package is not compatible with python 3.7 and it keeps saying "syntax error"

I have tried some method posted on the Github about this issue(https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/3143), but none of them solve it. I wonder whether I need to shift to python 3.6 or not? cause my python spider can only setup it's downloader and cannot parse webpages

Could anyone please give me some advise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  Twisted does not yet support Python 3.7.  Try Python 3.6 or earlier.

Comment: It does now as of January 2019 or some time earlier.

Answer (score 1):

One of the comments from [the issue](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/3143) helped me:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy@master --no-dependencies --upgrade
```

Comment: i moved my project to python 3.6. i will try you suggestion later.