# Python3 script stops working after scrapy update

Tags: python-3.x, encoding, scrapy, twisted

I am on `macOS 10.14.2` using "homebrewed" `python3.7.2`, `scrapy 1.5.1` and `twisted 18.9.0` as a python novice with the following script to download old newspaper archived on a website:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# A scrapy script to download issues of the Gaceta (1843-1961)

import errno
import json
import os
from datetime import datetime

import scrapy
from scrapy import FormRequest, Request

os.chdir("/Volumes/backup/Archives/Gaceta_Nicaragua_1843-1961") # directory path
print((os.getcwd()))

# date range, format DD/MM/YYYY
start = '01/01/1843' # 01/01/1843
end = '31/12/1860' # 31/12/1961

date_format = '%d/%m/%Y'
start = datetime.strptime(start, date_format)
end = datetime.strptime(end, date_format)

class AsambleaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'asamblea'
    allowed_domains = ['asamblea.gob.ni']
    start_urls = ['http://digesto.asamblea.gob.ni/consultas/coleccion/']

    papers = {
        "Diario Oficial": "28",
    }

    def parse(self, response):

        for key, value in list(self.papers.items()):
            yield FormRequest(url='http://digesto.asamblea.gob.ni/consultas/util/ws/proxy.php',
                  headers= {
                      'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
                  }, formdata= {
                        'hddQueryType': 'initgetRdds',
                        'cole': value
                    }
                    , meta={'paper': key},
                    callback=self.parse_rdds
                )
        pass

    def parse_rdds(self, response):
        data = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
        for r in data["rdds"]:
            if not r['fecPublica']:
                continue

            r_date = datetime.strptime(r['fecPublica'], date_format)

            if start <= r_date <= end:
                r['paper'] = response.meta['paper']
                rddid = r['rddid']
                yield Request("http://digesto.asamblea.gob.ni/consultas/util/pdf.php?type=rdd&rdd=" + rddid,
                              callback=self.download_pdf, meta=r)

    def download_pdf(self, response):
       filename = "{paper}/{anio}/".format(**response.meta) + "{titulo}-{fecPublica}.pdf".format(**response.meta).replace("/", "_")
       if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(filename)):
           try:
               os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(filename))
           except OSError as exc:  # guard against race condition
               if exc.errno != errno.EEXIST:
                   raise

       with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
           f.write(response.body)
```

It worked perfectly fine (although slow), however, I have two persisting issues with the script.

**Firstly**, I get the following error since the update:

```
2019-01-07 11:53:34 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <POST http://digesto.asamblea.gob.ni/consultas/util/ws/proxy.php> (referer: http://digesto.asamblea.gob.ni/consultas/coleccion/)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 102, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/offsite.py", line 30, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/referer.py", line 339, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/urllength.py", line 37, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/depth.py", line 58, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "gaceta_downloader.py", line 58, in parse_rdds
    if not r['fecPublica']:
KeyError: 'fecPublica'
```

**Secondly**, once the script runs again (as it did some days ago before updating python and packages) I ran into an issue where the script would sometimes complain that `UnicodeEncodeError: ‘ascii’ codec can’t encode character u’\xb0’ in position 27: ordinal not in range(128)` which I guess let sometimes to zero byte files. Do you see the encoding error in the source code? Is this related to the above problem?

Comment: maybe update Twisted by running `pip install Twisted --upgrade`

Comment: Thank you for replying, Umair. Unfortunately, the above command does not solve the issue. `Pip` reinstalls twisted, but the error persists.

Comment: [Answer: Twisted does not yet support Python 3.7.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51939690/2375183) might be the answer to my problem. However, this was mid-August, has twisted not yet been updated as suggested [here](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/milestone/Python%203.7%20support)?

Comment: Try with python 3.6, using the same code and versions of your libraries and you will know if this is related to python 3.7 compatibility.

Comment: Hi Guillaume, thank you for commenting. I updated the packages recently for all python versions I have to no avail. The script continues to stop without an error given. Any more suggestions?